# Top 20 Group Ranking Query - Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am creating a reporting structure where I need to output the top 20 days of aggregate stats for each unique Company - Region. I have completed this task but feel that my code is overly complicated and I am requesting help optimizing it.

I have 2 tables involved in this process. The first lists all the possible Company - Region - Group - Subgroups. The second has hourly stats by the Group - Subgroup.

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a7b/1
**NOTE**: currently getting a `SELECT command denied to user '<user>'@'<ip>' for table 'table_stats'` error on my SQL Fiddle, would appreciate help resolving this as well.

**table_companies declaration and dummy data:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_companies` (
  `pk_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subgroup` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pk_id_id_UNIQUE` (`pk_id`)
);

INSERT INTO table_companies
    (`pk_id`, `company`, `region`, `group`, `subgroup`)
VALUES
    (1, 'company1', 'region1', 'group1', 'subgroup1'),
    (2, 'company1', 'region1', 'group1', 'subgroup2'),
    (3, 'company1', 'region2', 'group2', 'subgroup3'),
    (4, 'company1', 'region3', 'group3', 'subgroup4'),
    (5, 'company2', 'region1', 'group4', 'subgroup5'),
    (6, 'company2', 'region3', 'group5', 'subgroup6'),
    (7, 'company2', 'region3', 'group6', 'subgroup7'),
    (8, 'company2', 'region4', 'group7', 'subgroup8'),
    (9, 'company2', 'region5', 'group8', 'subgroup9'),
    (10, 'company3', 'region6', 'group9', 'subgroup10'),
    (11, 'company3', 'region7', 'group10', 'subgroup11'),
    (12, 'company3', 'region8', 'group11', 'subgroup12'),
    (13, 'company4', 'region9', 'group12', 'subgroup13'),
    (14, 'company4', 'region10', 'group13', 'subgroup14'),
    (15, 'company5', 'region11', 'group14', 'subgroup15'),
    (16, 'company5', 'region12', 'group15', 'subgroup16')
;
```

**table_stats declaration:**
*Simplified to only contain a couple of the hours per day for only 1 group - subgroup.*

```
CREATE TABLE `table_stats` (
  `pk_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subgroup` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `stat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pk_id_UNIQUE` (`pk_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `om_unique` (`date_time`,`group`,`subgroup`)
);

INSERT INTO table_stats
    (`pk_id`, `date_time`, `group`, `subgroup`, `stat`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-12-01 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 14),
    (2, '2015-12-01 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 14),
    (3, '2015-12-02 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 2),
    (4, '2015-12-02 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 51),
    (5, '2015-12-03 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 30),
    (6, '2015-12-03 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 6),
    (7, '2015-12-04 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 9),
    (8, '2015-12-04 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 77),
    (9, '2015-12-05 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 70),
    (10, '2015-12-05 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 7),
    (11, '2015-12-06 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 38),
    (12, '2015-12-06 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 5),
    (13, '2015-12-07 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 86),
    (14, '2015-12-07 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 73),
    (15, '2015-12-08 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 45),
    (16, '2015-12-08 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 14),
    (17, '2015-12-09 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 66),
    (18, '2015-12-09 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 38),
    (19, '2015-12-10 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 12),
    (20, '2015-12-10 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 77),
    (21, '2015-12-11 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 21),
    (22, '2015-12-11 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 18),
    (23, '2015-12-12 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 28),
    (24, '2015-12-12 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 74),
    (25, '2015-12-13 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 20),
    (26, '2015-12-13 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 37),
    (27, '2015-12-14 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 66),
    (28, '2015-12-14 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 59),
    (29, '2015-12-15 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 26),
    (30, '2015-12-15 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 0),
    (31, '2015-12-16 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 77),
    (32, '2015-12-16 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 31),
    (33, '2015-12-17 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 59),
    (34, '2015-12-17 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 71),
    (35, '2015-12-18 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 7),
    (36, '2015-12-18 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 73),
    (37, '2015-12-19 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 72),
    (38, '2015-12-19 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 28),
    (39, '2015-12-20 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 50),
    (40, '2015-12-20 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 11),
    (41, '2015-12-21 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 71),
    (42, '2015-12-21 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 4),
    (43, '2015-12-22 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 78),
    (44, '2015-12-22 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 69),
    (45, '2015-12-23 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 83),
    (46, '2015-12-23 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 55),
    (47, '2015-12-24 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 71),
    (48, '2015-12-24 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 20),
    (49, '2015-12-25 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 90),
    (50, '2015-12-25 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 26),
    (51, '2015-12-26 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 1),
    (52, '2015-12-26 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 73),
    (53, '2015-12-27 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 4),
    (54, '2015-12-27 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 18),
    (55, '2015-12-28 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 4),
    (56, '2015-12-28 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 30),
    (57, '2015-12-29 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 56),
    (58, '2015-12-29 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 53),
    (59, '2015-12-30 06:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 33),
    (60, '2015-12-31 12:00:00', 'group9', 'subgroup10', 8)
;
```

**Query to optimize:**

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT t3.company,t3.region,t3.day, t3.day_stat,COUNT(*) as rank
    FROM
        (
            SELECT t2.company,t2.region,DAY(t1.date_time) as day,SUM(t1.stat) as day_stat
            FROM schema1.table_stats t1
            INNER JOIN table_companies t2
            ON t1.group=t2.group AND t1.subgroup=t2.subgroup
            WHERE
                MONTH(t1.date_time)=12 AND
                YEAR(t1.date_time)=2015
            group by t2.company,t2.region,DAY(t1.date_time)
            ORDER BY t2.company,t2.region,day_stat DESC
        ) t3
    JOIN
    (
            SELECT t2.company,t2.region,DAY(t1.date_time) as day,SUM(t1.stat) as day_stat
            FROM schema1.table_stats t1
            INNER JOIN table_companies t2
            ON t1.group=t2.group AND t1.subgroup=t2.subgroup
            WHERE
                MONTH(t1.date_time)=12 AND
                YEAR(t1.date_time)=2015
            group by t2.company,t2.region,DAY(t1.date_time)
            ORDER BY t2.company,t2.region,day_stat DESC
        ) t4
    ON
        t4.day_stat >= t3.day_stat AND
        t4.company = t3.company AND
        t4.region = t3.region
    GROUP BY t3.company,t3.region,t3.day_stat
    ORDER BY t3.company,t3.region,rank
    ) t5
WHERE t5.rank<=20
;
```

**Summary of query:** from the 2 deepest subqueries it starts by joining both tables, grouping and aggregating the `stat` by the company, region and day. This is also where it restricts the month and year. Then it joins this result to a duplicate of itself to be able to generate the rank. Last select limits results to top 20 for each subgroup.

**Expected result:**
*Apologies for presenting as a SQL declaration*

```
INSERT INTO results
    (`company`, `region`, `day`, `day_stat`, `rank`)
VALUES
    ('company3', 'region6', 7, 159, 1),
    ('company3', 'region6', 22, 147, 2),
    ('company3', 'region6', 23, 138, 3),
    ('company3', 'region6', 17, 130, 4),
    ('company3', 'region6', 14, 125, 5),
    ('company3', 'region6', 25, 116, 6),
    ('company3', 'region6', 29, 109, 7),
    ('company3', 'region6', 16, 108, 8),
    ('company3', 'region6', 9, 104, 9),
    ('company3', 'region6', 12, 102, 10),
    ('company3', 'region6', 19, 100, 11),
    ('company3', 'region6', 24, 91, 12),
    ('company3', 'region6', 10, 89, 13),
    ('company3', 'region6', 4, 86, 14),
    ('company3', 'region6', 18, 80, 15),
    ('company3', 'region6', 5, 77, 16),
    ('company3', 'region6', 21, 75, 17),
    ('company3', 'region6', 26, 74, 18),
    ('company3', 'region6', 20, 61, 19),
    ('company3', 'region6', 8, 59, 20)
;
```

tl;dr: Apologies for the long post. Asking to optimize http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a7b/1.

Comment: The error is because you try to use `schema1.tablename`

Comment: did you create any index?

Comment: Rather than using strings for company/region/group/subgroup have you considered having tables for those and making the references in the main tables be the ID in those tables?  Comparing integers (what the ID will be) is much faster than strings.  And it makes a better structure, you could have other info on the companies that you don't want to duplicate each time in the main table.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` _is_ a `UNIQUE KEY`, so don't make a redundant index.

Comment: The query is a bit messy.  [_Groupwise max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) outlines the code you need.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There is no error on the query. This question is rather around optimizing the query, though I should have added that the bigger concern here is not performance but rather to consolidate some of the code that could be overly complicated. This query will be run once monthly so real time performance is very small concern. The bigger concerns is, as this query is only a first part of some complicated calculations, how big the full query will grow to. Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: @nbayly I mean the error on the sqlFiddle is because you try to use a schema doesnt exist.

Comment: Your query works, performance isnt an issue,  So you want a simplification/reduction?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza seems like sqlfiddle is having issues cause I did create the schema (though now it's not loading). Due to these issues I copied all the statements into my posting. You might have to create the schema in sqlfiddle by copying and pasting. **Yes the question is around simplification/reduction.** For example without the last query, I tried referencing `rank` to limit to the top 20 but it kept giving me: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rank' in 'where clause'` which is why I had to wrap it in a final query that limits to the top 20.

Comment: That wrap is a must. You cant reference alias on the same level you declare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modifications I've made:

- Completely modified your query
- Added a composite index in `table_companies` table on `group,subgroup`
- Added a composite index in `table_stats` table on `group, subgroup`

---

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT 
    C.company,
    C.region,
    DAY(S.date_time) day,
    SUM(S.stat) day_stat
FROM table_companies C
INNER JOIN table_stats S
ON C.`group` = S.`group` AND C.subgroup = S.subgroup
WHERE MONTH(S.date_time) = 12 AND YEAR(S.date_time) = 2015
GROUP BY C.company, C.region, DAY(S.date_time)
ORDER BY day_stat DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

<kbd>**[WORKING DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a7b/5/0)**</kbd>

<sub>There's no rank column in the result set. Since the results are sorted according to rank in descending order so that you can implicitly treat the position of a row in the result set as the rank. Nevertheless if you really need the rank column then here is a [**working demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a7b/6/0) of it</sub>

**Composite index(`table_companies)`:**

```
ALTER TABLE `table_companies` ADD INDEX `idx_table_compnaies_group_subgroup` (
    `group`,
    `subgroup`
);
```

**Composite index(`table_stats)`:**

```
ALTER TABLE `table_stats` ADD INDEX `idx_table_stats_group_subgroup` (
`group`,
`subgroup`
);
```

**Explain Result:**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  S   ALL idx_table_compnaies_group_subgroup              60  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  C   ref idx_table_companies_group_subgroup  idx_table_companies_group_subgroup  57  schema1.S.group,schema1.S.subgroup  1   Using index condition
```

<sub>Good news is MySQL can use these `indexes`(because these are under **possible keys**). Although it's showing `ALL` as type for `table_companies`. All I can say it's a small set of data. **You cannot judge performance based on small set of data.**</sub>

**More:**

I guess you have primary keys in those tables. If you don't have any then create.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
    C.company,
    C.region,
    tt.day,
    tt.total AS day_stat,
    tt.rank
FROM table_companies C 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
t.*,
IF(t.businessUnit = @sameBusinessUnit, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) AS rank,
@sameBusinessUnit := t.businessUnit
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
       S1.`group`,
       S1.subgroup,
       CONCAT(S1.`group`,S1.subgroup) AS businessUnit,
       DAY(S1.date_time) AS day,
       SUM(S1.stat) total
    FROM table_stats S1
    GROUP BY S1.group,S1.subgroup,DAY(S1.date_time)
    ORDER BY total DESC
)AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 1, @sameBusinessUnit := '') var
) AS tt
ON C.`group`=tt.`group` AND C.subgroup = tt.subgroup
WHERE tt.rank <= 20
ORDER BY tt.`group`,tt.`subgroup`,tt.rank;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO(Version 2.0)**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29a7b/9/0)</kbd>

Comment: This is similar than one of my initial iterations I tried but decided to drop this method in particular due to `LIMIT 20` will only provide the top 20 for all the possible Company - Region - Group - Subgroups. I require the top 20 for each separate business unit. My apologies as my data suggested this would be a viable solutions but I included only 1 unit for presentation purposes. Total results should be the amount of business units times 20. Looking forward to any other solutions you might find. Regards.

Comment: How do you identify each separate **business unit**? And do you want top 20 result for each **business unit**? @nbayly

Comment: Please clarify that which fields together uniquely identify a business unit. And if there are 5 unique business units then there will be at most 5*20 = 100 rows in your result set. is it?

Comment: Each business unit is each unique Company - Region - Group - Subgroups and yes I require the top 20 results for each biz unit as defined. In the case of the sample table _companies I provided there would be 16 biz units * 20 = 320 rows needed to be returned.

Comment: Since business unit = unique combination of `Company - Region - Group - Subgroups` then you should group by `Company - Region - Group - Subgroups`. But in the query you used only `company and region`

Comment: And one more important question: the two tables can only be related by group and subgroup. how do u know which groups & subgroups in `table_stat` table relate to the groups and subgroups in `table_companies` table? Since multiple `company,region` pair can have same groups and subgroups

Comment: The group-subgroups will always be unique. There might be some textual matches between Regions and Groups, but the group-subgroup combination will never be repeated for other business units. Regards.

Comment: Actually my mistake, what I need is rather the top 20 of each Region by adding all the group - subgroups in each. This is why I group to the Company - Region. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Then the `group,subgroup` combination can uniquely identify a business unit. right? If yes then no need to group by those 4 fields. Please ensure this. The answer fully depends on this particular information.

Comment: Please check the updated answer under edit section. If you find any discrepancy please let me know. @nbayly

Answer (score 0):

Just include one index for group so the join become more efficient

```
CREATE TABLE table_companies
    (`pk_id` int, `company` varchar(8), 
     `region` varchar(8), `group` varchar(7), `subgroup` varchar(10),
     PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `pk_id_id_UNIQUE` (`pk_id`),  

     INDEX idx_group (`group`, `subgroup`)
    )
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Again the question is around simplification/reduction of the code. Performance is not a concern as the datasets are not large and it is an ad hoc process rather than operational. The problem is that I have to keep adding calculations to this query and I'm concerned with the readability and over complexity.